# Kalman Gain from given Variances

Tags: parameter-estimation, kalman-filter

$$x[n]=0.6x[n-1]+w[n]$$
$$y[n]=x[n]+v[n]$$
$$\sigma_w^2=0.25, $$$$\sigma_v^2=0.5$$

Find the expression for the Kalman filter equation at convergence and the corresponding mean square error.

I know Kalman filter equation is 
$$\hat{x}_k=A\hat{x}_{k-1}+Bu_k+K_k(y_k-C(A\hat{x}_{k-1}+Bu_k))$$

But here $u_k=0$
then it reduces to 
$$\hat{x}_k=A\hat{x}_{k-1}+K_k(y_k-C(A\hat{x}_{k-1}))$$

But how to calculate Kalman gain from given variances? Please help me in solving this.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Are you using a book or other resource to learn from? If so, what does that say and where do you get stuck?